# What is the new label in polkadot-sdk to track runtime migrations?

Tags: storage-migration, polkadot-sdk

We used to have `E0-runtime-migration` labels to track storage migrations of FRAME pallets but I can't see anything on the new repo. Has one not been created yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all dependencies labels (`E*`) were deprecated since they've been used for releases only and we're aiming for a better release process with proper change logs